# Short circuit on one branch of parallel connection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electricity, electrical-resistance, short-circuits

[image: Circuit]
I don't understand how that extra branch that starts in (a) affects the circuit. If R4 did not exist, then r2 and r3 would be ignored but now you have to take into account the (b) knot. How can we calculate the equivalent resistance?

Comment: hint: $R_2$ and $R_3$ are connected now how?

Comment: If R4 did not exist (open branch), R2 and R3 would shorted leaving R1 and R5 in series with the battery.